# Anyway to extract Windows 10 network usage by app?

Tags: windows, windows-10

[image: Win 10 App usage]

Is there a way to extract/read via the data provided in Windows 10 App network usage, as seen in above photo? I have used procmon to record the events around this process, but cannot find where the data is pulled from.